# How to add minutes to a datetime range comparison?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, python-datetime

How can I alter the below to account for minutes as well as our in datetime range?

For example the below works fine.

```
from datetime import datetime

if (datetime.now().hour>=14) and (datetime.now().hour<=16):
         print ('afternoon' )

else:
        print ('not afternoon')
```

If the time now is past 14:30 but before 16:30 print afternoon.

Comment: Can you insert a minimal and reproducible example of your code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.minute

Comment: Sincerest apologies - formatting from my phone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `time` from `datetime` to make timeobjects. So you can create a time object for your start time and a time object for your end time. then you can just extract the timeobject from you datetime and compare it with a simple between expression. I have used timedelta, to just manipulate the current date time to show this working.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

datetimes = []
datetimes.append(datetime.now())
datetimes.append(datetimes[-1] + timedelta(hours=3, minutes=20))
datetimes.append(datetimes[-1] + timedelta(hours=3, minutes=20))
start_time = time(14, 30)
end_time = time(16, 30)
for current in datetimes:
    print(f"Time: {current.hour:02}:{current.minute:02}")
    if start_time <= current.time() <= end_time:
        print("afternoon")
    else:
        print("not afternoon")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Time: 11:22
not afternoon
Time: 14:42
afternoon
Time: 18:02
not afternoon
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime, time

def checkTime(t):
    if time(14, 30) <= t <= time(16, 30):
        print("time: " + t.strftime("%H") + "h" + " " + t.strftime("%M") + "m" + " is afternoon" )
    else:
        print("time: " + t.strftime("%H") + "h" + " " + t.strftime("%M") + "m" + " is not afternoon" )

checkTime(time(15,15)) # time: 15h 15m is afternoon
checkTime(time(14,30)) # time: 14h 30m is afternoon
checkTime(time(15,31)) # time: 15h 31m is afternoon
checkTime(time(14,29)) # time: 14h 29m is not afternoon
checkTime(time(16,31)) # time: 16h 31m is not afternoon
checkTime(time(18,10)) # time: 18h 10m is not afternoon
```

Comment: How does this check if the time is between 14:30 and 16:30?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: The part you added to your answer doesn't work. For example, it reports 15:15 as not afternoon. In fact, it won't report any time other than 14:30, 15:30, or 16:30 as afternoon, and there are a lot of times for which it won't print anything at all.

Comment: Also you should capture the time once and compare it not call dt.now again and again